# DirectX DrawText doesn't work

Tags: function, directx, drawtext

I have been learning DirectX and Windows programming for a short time now. However, I have a problem with the DirectX function `DrawText`. Somehow it doesn't display text in the window, and cannot figure out why. Here is my code:

main.cpp

```
//Include's
#include"winwindow.hpp"
#include<time.h>
#include<iostream>
//main
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,LPSTR lpCmdLine,int nCmdShow){
    c_winwindow window(hInstance,nCmdShow);
    bool b_init=false;
    b_init=window.init(); 
    while(b_init){
        window.clear(D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0xEF,0xEF,0xEF));
        window.drawtext(0,0,L"Halo",D3DCOLOR_COLORVALUE(0xFF,0,0,0xFF));
        window.display();
        b_init=window.update();
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

winwindow.hpp

```
//Include's
#include"windows.h"
#include"d3d9.h"
#include"d3dx9.h"
//c_winwindow
class c_winwindow{
    private:
        HWND hwnd;
        MSG msg;
        HINSTANCE hInstance;
        int nCmdShow;
        bool b_init;
        static LRESULT CALLBACK Messagehandler(HWND hwnd,UINT msg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam);
        LPDIRECT3D9 lpd3d;
        LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 lpd3ddevice;
        ID3DXFont *p_d3dfont;
        bool initwin();
        bool initdx();
    public:
        c_winwindow(const HINSTANCE &hInstance,int nCmdShow);
        ~c_winwindow();
        bool init();
        bool update();
        void clear(D3DCOLOR clr);
        void display();
        void drawtext(unsigned short int,unsigned short int,LPCWSTR,D3DCOLOR);
};
```

winwindow.cpp

```
//Include's
#include"winwindow.hpp"
#include<iostream>
//c_winwindow memberfunction's
//konstruktor
c_winwindow::c_winwindow(const HINSTANCE &temphInstance,int tempnCmdShow){
    hInstance=temphInstance;
    nCmdShow=tempnCmdShow;
    hwnd=NULL;
    lpd3d=NULL;
    lpd3ddevice=NULL;
    b_init=false;
}
//destruktor
c_winwindow::~c_winwindow(){
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    hwnd=NULL;
    if(lpd3d!=NULL){
        lpd3d->Release();
        lpd3d=NULL;
    }
    if(lpd3ddevice!=NULL){
        lpd3ddevice->Release();
        lpd3ddevice=NULL;
    }
    if(p_d3dfont!=NULL){
        p_d3dfont->Release();
        p_d3dfont=NULL;
    }
}
//initwin
bool c_winwindow::initwin(){
    if(!b_init){
        WNDCLASS wc;
        ZeroMemory(&wc,sizeof(wc));
        wc.lpfnWndProc=Messagehandler;
        wc.hInstance=hInstance;
        wc.lpszClassName=L"wndc";
        RegisterClass(&wc);
        hwnd=CreateWindow(L"wndc",L"TestWindow",WS_SYSMENU,10,10,1200,800,NULL,NULL,hInstance,NULL);
        if(hwnd==NULL){
            std::cout << "failed to create Window!" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }else{
            b_init=true;
            ShowWindow(hwnd,nCmdShow);
            return true;
        }
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
//initdx
bool c_winwindow::initdx(){
    lpd3d=Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);
    if(lpd3d==NULL){
        std::cout << "couldn't create direct3d Object" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS params;
    ZeroMemory(&params,sizeof(params));
    params.SwapEffect=D3DSWAPEFFECT_FLIP;
    params.hDeviceWindow=hwnd;
    params.Windowed=true;
    params.BackBufferWidth=1200;
    params.BackBufferHeight=800;
    params.BackBufferFormat= D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8;
    if(FAILED(lpd3d->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,hwnd,D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,&params,&lpd3ddevice))){
        std::cout << "couldn't create direct3d device" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    if(D3D_OK!=D3DXCreateFont(lpd3ddevice,22,0,FW_NORMAL,1,false,DEFAULT_CHARSET,OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS,ANTIALIASED_QUALITY,DEFAULT_PITCH|FF_DONTCARE,L"Arial",&p_d3dfont)){
        std::cout << "couldn't create font" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
} 
//init
bool c_winwindow::init(){
    return initwin()&&initdx();
}
//update
bool c_winwindow::update(){
    if(b_init){
        if(GetMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0)){
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
            return true;
        }else{
            if(lpd3d!=NULL){
                lpd3d->Release();
                lpd3d=NULL;
            }
            if(lpd3ddevice!=NULL){
                lpd3ddevice->Release();
                lpd3ddevice=NULL;
            }
            hwnd=NULL;
            b_init=false;
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
//clear
void c_winwindow::clear(D3DCOLOR clr){
    lpd3ddevice->Clear(0,0,D3DCLEAR_TARGET,clr,0,0);
    lpd3ddevice->BeginScene();
}
//display 
void c_winwindow::display(){
    lpd3ddevice->EndScene();
    lpd3ddevice->Present(0,0,0,0);
}
void c_winwindow::drawtext(unsigned short int us_x,unsigned short int us_y,LPCWSTR text,D3DCOLOR textcolor){
    RECT r;
    SetRect(&r,us_x,us_y,0,0);
    p_d3dfont->DrawText(NULL,text,-1,&r,DT_LEFT,textcolor);
}
//WndProc
LRESULT CALLBACK c_winwindow::Messagehandler(HWND hwnd,UINT msg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam){
    switch(msg){
        case(WM_DESTROY):
            PostQuitMessage(0); 
            return 0;
        break;
        case(WM_PAINT):
            return 0;
        break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd,msg,wParam,lParam);
}
```

The window appears grey, with no text in it. Can anyone explain why there is no text?

Comment: You should learn DX11 this day and age. DX9 is already obsolete technology, old as time. So, especially as you're just learning this, go for DX11 + D2D.